# jquery json anchor tag

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, and am passing back json formatted rows. One of the values of the row is an anchor tag as below:

```
<a class='class1' href='#' onClick='getFn(); return false;'> text </a>
```

But The returned JSON converts the values as below:

```
"\n text\n <\/a>"
```

It removes all the attributes and also the "tag" at the beginning. Is there a workaround for this kind of problem?

**JSON Sample of my resultset**

```
{"ROWS":[[3,"FName1","Lname1","\n text\n <\/a>"]],"PAGE":1.0,"TOTAL":3.0,"RECORDS":1}
```

So in the above sample, the value `"\n text\n <\/a>"` should have been `<a class='class1' href='#' onClick='getFn(); return false;'> text </a>`

Coldfusion Code:

```
     //append to the array
     <cfset arrayAppend(arrayUsers[i],"<a class='class1' href='#' onClick='getFn(); return false;'> text </a>")>

  </cfloop>
 <cfset i = i + 1>
```

Final json formatted string to return

```
<cfset jsonReturn = {total=#totalPages#,page=#Arguments.page#,records=#GetDetails.recordcount#,rows=#arrayUsers#}>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show a more complete example of the _"JSON formatted rows?"_ Could you clarify what you mean by _"the returned JSON converts the values"_ and _"it removes all attributes"_? What's "it" - jqgrid?

Comment: @Matt: I edited my response with sample JSON. What I meant by "returned JSON converts the values", I built an array using Coldfusion that has to be passed to JSON. coldfusion displays the anchor tags fine, but json escapes tags and removes the attributes before passing them to jqgrid.'It' referes to jSON. Thanks

Comment: @user: I still don't get what you mean. JSON is a notation; it doesn't _do_ anything, so I don't see how it could escape the tags and remove the attributes. Do you mean that the JSON converter you're using (or perhaps CF) is doing this?

Comment: @Matt. I updated my question with Coldfusion code. When I see the Coldfusion result separately, I see the full anchor tag, but when I see the json returned to jqgrid in firebug, the anchor tag is all escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<cfsavecontent>`:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="a"><a class='class1' href='#' onClick='getFn(); return false;'> text </a></cfsavecontent>
```

```
<cfset arrayAppend(arrayUsers[i], a)>
```

Comment: The problem is that the closing > in your arrayAppend call is being seen as the end of the tag (it really should throw an error, surprised it's not).  Using cfsavecontent will preserve the formatting of the link.

Comment: I tried using your code. I now see the link, but the value on grid is surrounded by extra characters like '\r\ntext\r\n'. The returned json has this value for the anchor tag: \\r\\n k <\/a>\\r\\n